# Why does it not return the value?

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >0.4.22 <0.7.0;


contract WhileLoop {

    uint8 number=1;
   
    function retrieve() public returns (uint8){
        
        while(number != 4){
            number++;
        }
        
        return number;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are changing the contract state. Transactions that change the contract state will return to you the transaction hash. If you want to get the value of a variable you need to use a constant function. If you add this code, then it will work:

```
function checkNumber() public view returns(uint8){
   return number;
}
```